# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - Wordpress Migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm in the process of migrating a local Wordpress website to its live domain. Everything works perfectly when hosted locally (MAMP), but when uploaded to my domain, it gets stuck on the loader and gives me this error in Chrome's console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
/* LOADER */
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery(".status").fadeOut();
    jQuery(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
});

/** BACKGROUND SLIDER ***/
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if ( jQuery('.fadein-slider .slide-item').length > 1 ) {
        jQuery('.fadein-slider .slide-item:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
            jQuery('.fadein-slider :first-child').fadeOut(2000).next('.slide-item').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.fadein-slider');
        }, 10000);
    }
});

/*** DROPDOWN FOR MOBILE MENU */
var callback_mobile_dropdown = function () {
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 767 ){

        jQuery('#site-navigation li').each(function(){

            if ( jQuery(this).find('ul').length > 0 ){
                jQuery(this).addClass('has_children');
                jQuery(this).find('a').first().after('<p class="dropdownmenu"></p>');
            }

        });

    }

    jQuery('.dropdownmenu').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).parent('li').hasClass('this-open') ){
            jQuery(this).parent('li').removeClass('this-open');
        }else{
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('this-open');
        }
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(callback_mobile_dropdown);
jQuery(window).resize(callback_mobile_dropdown);


/* show/hide reCaptcha */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var thisOpen = false;
  jQuery('.contact-form .form-control').each(function(){
    if ( (typeof jQuery(this).val() != 'undefined') && (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) ){
      thisOpen = true;
      jQuery('.g-recaptcha').css('display','block').delay(1000).css('opacity','1');
      return false;
    }
  });
  if ( thisOpen == false && (typeof jQuery('.contact-form textarea').val() != 'undefined') && (jQuery('.contact-form textarea').val().length > 0) ) {
    thisOpen = true;
    jQuery('.g-recaptcha').css('display','block').delay(1000).css('opacity','1');
  }
  jQuery('.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea').focus(function(){
    if ( !jQuery('.g-recaptcha').hasClass('recaptcha-display') ) {
        jQuery('.g-recaptcha').css('display','block').delay(1000).css('opacity','1');
    }
  });

});

/* Bootstrap Fix */
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {

    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')

    msViewportStyle.appendChild(

        document.createTextNode(

            '@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'

        )

    )

    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle);

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /*** SMOOTH SCROLL TO FRONPAGE SECTIONS */  
    /* when click on menu item that correspons to a section scroll to that section */
    jQuery('.main-nav-list a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = jQuery(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                jQuery('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1200);
                return false;
            }
        }

    });

    /** BACKGROUND IMAGE ONLY FOR FRONTPAGE **/
    jQuery('body:not(.home)').removeClass('custom-background');

    /* PARALLAX */
    var jQuerywindow = jQuery(window);

    jQuery('div[data-type="background"], header[data-type="background"], section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){

        var jQuerybgobj = jQuery(this);

        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

            var yPos = -(jQuerywindow.scrollTop() / jQuerybgobj.data('speed'));

            var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

            jQuerybgobj.css({ 

                backgroundPosition: coords 

            });

        });

    });

});

jQuery(window).load(function() {

    /* FOOTER */
    /* vp_h will hold the height of the browser window */
    var vp_h = jQuery(window).height();

    /* b_g will hold the height of the html body */
    var b_g = jQuery('body').height();

    /* If the body height is lower than window */
    if(b_g < vp_h) {

        jQuery('footer').css("position","absolute");
        jQuery('footer').css("bottom","0px");
        jQuery('footer').css("width","100%");

    }

    /* SUBSCRIBE  */
    jQuery("form :input").each(function(index, elem) {

        var eId = jQuery(elem).attr("class");

        if( (eId == "sib-email-area") || (eId == "sib-NAME-area") ) {

            var label = null;
            if (eId && (label = jQuery(elem).parents("form").find("label."+eId)).length == 1) {
                jQuery(elem).attr("placeholder", jQuery(label).html());
                jQuery(label).remove();
            }
        }
    });
}); 


/* TOP NAVIGATION MENU SELECTED ITEMS */
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    var zerif_scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var zerif_windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();

    jQuery("section").each( function() {

        var zerif_offset = jQuery(this).offset();

        if (zerif_scrollTop <= zerif_offset.top && (jQuery(this).height() + zerif_offset.top) < (zerif_scrollTop + zerif_windowHeight) ) {

            jQuery('ul.nav > li a').each( function() {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('nav-active');
            });

            var zerif_current_id_visible = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            jQuery('ul.nav > li a').each( function() {
                if( jQuery(this).attr('href').indexOf(zerif_current_id_visible) >= 0 ) {
                    jQuery('ul.nav > li a').each( function() {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('nav-active');
                    });
                    jQuery(this).addClass('nav-active');
                }

            });
        }

    });

});


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setminHeightHeader();
});

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    setminHeightHeader();
    cloneMenu();
});

function setminHeightHeader() 
{
    jQuery('#main-nav').css('min-height','75px');
    jQuery('.header').css('min-height','75px');
    var minHeight = parseInt( jQuery('#main-nav').height() );
    jQuery('#main-nav').css('min-height',minHeight);
    jQuery('.header').css('min-height',minHeight);
}

function cloneMenu()
{
    jQuery( '.collapse.in').removeClass('in');
    jQuery( '.navbar-toggle.collapsed').removeClass('collapsed');
}
```

I'm not very familiar with editing javascript, so if anyone sees any glaring errors, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Chrome console should also tell you the line of the error, if you click on the error code...

Comment: It says line 1 - but I think the entire script is on one line.

Comment: Any other differences between staging and production environments?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your site is not loading jquery. Check whether the Jquery js is served properly to the client. I myself wasted a lot of time debugging the same error, turns out the server was configured not to serve files directly to the client unless served from a servlet. Might be a similar case.Since the browser can't locate Jquery identifier this would most likely be the reason.